# Yii2 dropDownList: add attributes for each item

Tags: php, yii2

I want to generate a dropdown with an additional attribute for each `option` item like this:

```
<select>
    <option value="1" data-height="45">item 1</option>
    <option value="2" data-height="70">item 2</option>
    <option value="3" data-height="10">item 3</option>
</select>
```

is there a proper way to generate it as this none-correct example:

DB model, retrived rows:

```
[
{id: 1, name: "item 1", height: 45},
{id: 2, name: "item 2", height: 70},
{id: 3, name: "item 3", height: 10},
]
```

PHP:

```
<?php 
$form->field($model, $attribute)->dropDownList($items_array, $options, function($item) {
    return "<option value='{$item->id}' data-height='{$item->height}'>{$item->name}</option>";
})
 ?>
```

Comment: `{somthing from model in this row 1}` is it the same thing for each option?

Comment: @EdvinTenovimas its value becomes different on each row

Comment: But how are you able to identify what it's supposed to be in each row (row number, etc.)? Can you give me an example what do you want to insert from model?

Comment: @EdvinTenovimas I updated my question. `height` is another field in each row

Comment: For those who do not yet have it. Refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54476053/yii2-add-extra-attribute-in-select-options-list).

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php 
// Get Array from Database
     $items_array = ArrayHelper::map(ModelName::find()->asArray()->all(),'id','name'); 
?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'designation')->dropDownList($items_array,['prompt' => 'Select Any One', 'data-height="45",'class' => 'form-control']); ?>
```