# Yii2 add extra attribute in select > options list

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

How I can add an extra attribute like in below screenshot `state_id=1` in options list for all.

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'district_id')->dropDownList(ArrayHelper::map($Districts, 'id', 'name')) ?>
```

[image: screenshot of form]

Comment: show your code snippet

Comment: <?= $form->field($model, 'district_id')->dropDownList(ArrayHelper::map($Districts, 'id', 'name')) ?>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to iterate through the `$Districts` array and associate all the attributes you want to add to the `<option>` of the dropdown, i assume that your `$Districts` array has something like below

```
$Districts=[
    1=>"North Andaman",
    2=>"South Andaman"
    3=>"Nicobar"
];
```

Now you need to iterate that array and associate the attributes with every option

```
foreach ($Districts as $id => $name) {
    $optionAttributes[$id] = ['my-attr' => 'value'];
}
```

The above will show you something like

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [my-attr] => value
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [my-attr] => value
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [my-attr] => value
        )

)
```

Now when creating your dropdown you should pass this array to the `options` option of the `dropdownList()` see below

```
echo $form->field($model, 'district_id')->dropDownList(
    $Districts,
    ['options' => $optionAttributes]
);
```

Now if you see the source of the page it will show you the dropdown like below

```
<select id="contacts-district_id" name="Contacts[district_id]" class="form-control">
    <option value="1" my-attr="value">North Andaman</option>
    <option value="2" my-attr="value">South Andaman</option>
    <option value="3" my-attr="value">Nicobar</option>
</select>
```